# I can't apply Facebook or Instagram icons in Font Awesome 5 as a content

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I can set a font awesome icon with the following style, which works fine:

```
.my-title:before{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f568";
 }
```

But I can't set neither Facebook nor Instagram icons. For example "f082" is the content for Facebook:

```
 .my-title:before{
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f082";
 }
```

Doesn't work even I remove font-weight, or change it to 400.

Thanks.

Comment: The brand icons are in a separate stylesheet. Can you show which files you've loaded?

Comment: @TiesonT. I directly included "/fontawesome/css/all.css". I can use facebook and instagram icons when I directly apply as a class, no problem with that. <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i> works fine.

Comment: The brand icons are also only 400 weight - what happens if you remove the weight from your ruleset?

Comment: I also tried 400. A square is shown.

Comment: you need to correct font-family

Comment: Yep. "Font Awesome 5 Brands" is the font-family for the brand icons.

Comment: OK, I solved the problem. Thank you.